# How do I load a javascript file dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function js() {
        var getJs = document.getElementById("jogo");

        if (JS == true) { //if button JS is pressed - it is correct?

            < script type = "text/javascript"
            src = "file1.js" >


        } else < script type = "text/javascript"
        src = "file2.js" >
</script>
}
</script>
```

it doesn't work. I gave two buttons, if the first is pressed, `file1.js` should be loaded. In case the second one is pressed, `file2.js` should be loaded.

How can I do that?

Comment: what you mean with eval? thanks

Comment: `if (JS == true)` dosent mean it being pressed, it simply mean that element is exist in the DOM and why dont u just include all the script and then call the appropriate function based on the existence of the JS

Comment: @user455318: eval is used to execute a string as Javascript code @kjy112: no you do not. Please do not suggest `eval` as solution unless it's the only way to do. Bad guides would suggest code like `eval("document."+id+".value="+numericValue)`. That is highly insecure!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You cannot embed HTML in Javascript in that way. Basically, what you want is to embed a script element, pointing to a certain javascript file when clicking a button. That can be done with combining events with DOM:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function loadJS(file) {
    // DOM: Create the script element
    var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
    // set the type attribute
    jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
    // make the script element load file
    jsElm.src = file;
    // finally insert the element to the body element in order to load the script
    document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
}
</script>
<button onclick="loadJS('file1.js');">Load file1.js</button>
<button onclick="loadJS('file2.js');">Load file2.js</button>
```

Comment: Please add note that functions from loaded javascript file are not available right after calling "document.body.appendChild(jsElm);", but there is jsElem.onload event that signals when js is ready.

Comment: What about using `document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='file.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));`

Comment: @Ithar `document.write` should be avoided, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Optimizing_your_pages_for_speculative_parsing

Comment: Hi, @Lekensteyn I was working with the same dynamic javascript loading. I have used the above-mentioned code but still, my page gets stuck for 2-3 seconds and then my loader is displayed. Any advice on why it is happening. Tried async attribute as well.

Comment: @DeepanksheeJain if you have a large file, it may take a while before the download is completed.

Answer (score 13):

Try this on for size: [Dynamically Load JS](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)

```
function loadjscssfile(filename){
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadjscssfile("myscript.js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
```

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript:

```
function loadScript(url)
{
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script")).src = url;
}
function loadDefaultScript()
{
    loadScript("http://mysite.com/file1.js");
}
function loadAlternateScript()
{
    loadScript("http://mysite.com/file2.js");
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="loadAlternateScript()" value="Alternate" />
<input type="button" onclick="loadDefaultScript()" value="Default" />
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the `type` parameter.

Comment: The `type` attribute is optional in HTML5.

Comment: The server is the authoritative source for the mime type.  The type attribute is always ignored, not just for HTML5.  There is no advantage to including it.  It's actually a disadvantage because it's misleading.

Comment: you can take a look at the link: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808425/how-load-and-use-dynamically-javascript/45489130#45489130)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function this will work perfectly

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
loadjscssfile("javascript.php", "js") //dynamically load "javascript.php" as a JavaScript file
loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
```

Comment: you can take a look at the link: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808425/how-load-and-use-dynamically-javascript/45489130#45489130)

Answer (score 0):

Via Jquery:

```
 var getJSfile = function(src) {
            var jsfile = $("<script type='text/javascript' src='"+src+"'>");
            $("head").append(jsfile); 
        }; 

    getJSfile ("home.js");
```

Comment: you can take a look at the link: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808425/how-load-and-use-dynamically-javascript/45489130#45489130)