# Include remote js file on the fly?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, include

Is there a simple way to include a remote js file on the fly (in an onclick function)?

The "verify" onclick event for our ssl site seal requires a code include from the vendor. Trouble is, it slows loads times. So I extracted the function from their js and hosted it locally - but they change the request params from time to time so I have to manually edit the js.

It would be nicer if I could just include the remote file when someone clicks the site seal.

TIA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I load a javascript file dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235321/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-dynamically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `createElement()` and add it to the DOM. Please see the below document.

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery you can use [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

**Description:** Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

Comment: thanks but i want to use as little js as possible and don't want to load up any other libraries such as moo tools or jquery.

Comment: So just look at Felix Kling comment : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235321/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-dynamically