# Defer Loading og jQuery.js except one Post Type

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, deferred, pagespeed

How can i Defer Loading of Jquery.js on all site except one Post Type?
Here is [site link](https://tenocation.com).
I tried to search almost all the forums but found nothing on this topic. It will be really helpful if anybody can help me out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I need a code for this query :-p ... Doesn't have any code to write here. This question had never been asked anywhere and might help alot of future visitors... Thanks Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply using the defer attribute on your markup like so:

```
 <script src="jquery.js" defer></script>
```

Or are you looking to dynamically defer the loading of the file? You might want to do something a little like this:

[How do I load a javascript file dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235321/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I want to defer jquery.js on all site except one post type. We can somehow possible use the if statement.