# I have 2 JS files. How do I make the 2nd JS file only run *after* the 1st JS file has finished loading?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 JS files. How do I make the 2nd JS file only run *after* the 1st JS file has finished loading? Is there a way to explicitly set this?

Answer (score 3):

Based on this answer [How do I load a javascript file dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235321/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-dynamically)

You can load the second file dynamically from the first one. This way you can be sure the first one is completely loaded.

```
  // DOM: Create the script element
var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
// set the type attribute
jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
// make the script element load file
jsElm.src = file;
// finally insert the element to the body element in order to load the script
document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have two js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="2.js"></script>
```

2.js

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
    fn1();
}
```

1.js

```
function fn1(){
 alert("external fn clicked");
}
```

---

OR

---

1.js:

```
function fn(){
   alert("Hello! HAPPY CODING");
}
```

2.js:

```
$.getscript("1.js",function(){
fn();
});
```

Hope This Helps...