# What exactly goes on inside document.write()?

Tags: javascript, dom

How exactly does document.write() work?

When I do

```
  document.write('<script src="file.js"><\/script>');
```

inside a **script** tag which is inside a **head** tag, document.write() inserts the tag within the **head** tag. (Since I've called it from within **head** tag)

When document.write is called after the page fully loads, it implicitly calls document.open() and then executes document.write()

My question is, 
after page load, when I call

```
document.write('hello');  //Inserts 'hello' within body tag
```

and when I call

```
document.write('<script src="file.js"><\/script>'); //Inserts within head tag
```

So how exactly does document.write() know what kind of string am I inserting? Does it parse the string too?

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235321/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-dynamically

Comment: `document.write()` does nothing more than what it's name implies.

Comment: @charlietfl And how does it decide, where in the document will it write? Within the body tag? Within the head tag?

Comment: No..exactly where it is placed. If used after page loaded will wipe out the whole page

Comment: @charlietfl True. And what after the wipe out? Try the 2nd and the 3rd code snippet on any web page

Comment: No idea what that means. Just don't use it...it is desctructive

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser treats all data inserted by `document.write` as if it came from the server, right after the script block which contains the `write`. So, if you `document.write('<script>alert(1);</' + 'script>');`, the browser will add another `<script>` element after the current one. Script blocks are executed no matter where they are, in the head or in the document body.

If the call to `document.write` happens after the page is loaded, a new document will be created.

Your third snippet will create an HTML document containing only a `<script>` tag. This is not valid HTML, so most browsers will magically create the `<html>` and `<head>` elements for you, and place the script element there.