# How to set script src path dynamically using Angular.js and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need one help.I need to set js/css path name dynamically uaing Angular.js/Javascript/Jquery.I am explaining my code below.

```
<script src="/crm/controller/productController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Suppose i have the above script tag.Here my path is
`/crm/controller/productController.js`.I need to set `/crm/` in my config file and i will set this path name in every script tag.In php it is happening like below.

```
define("USER_SITE_URL", "http://www.absclasses.com/");
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SITE_URL;?>js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

As i am not using PHP. How it can me made using Angular.js or Javascript/Jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load a javascript file dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235321/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-dynamically)

Comment: @KhalidHussain : meaning is totally different.

Comment: is that because you have different versions of these files in different folders ? can you give more details about why you want to do that ?

Comment: I think you don't want to write <?php echo SITE_URL;?> every time so for that you can add <base href="http://www.absclasses.com/"> tag in side your head tag of page and after it use <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @ranakrunal9 : I have already tested that if i am setting the `<base href="absclasses.com/">` then i have to add <script type="absclasses.com/text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> like this.that was the reason why i wanted to do it in config file because suppose the someday if the base href value is changed the i have to chahged in everywhere.

Comment: @Omar.Alani : Because i wanted to remove the `#` tag from angular.js.I have already explained above.Please see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML [base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) as follows.

```
<base href="http://www.absclasses.com/" />
```

If you want to do this with angular config block, you can use the following javascript code also with some modification.

```
document.write("<base href='http://" + document.location.host + "' />");
```

You can also define store document.location.host to a variable and use that.

Comment: Ok,I will check this and confirm you.so how can i set my script tag ?

Comment: Same way without the common part, which you are setting on base.

Comment: Hi,its good solution but one problem is there,i have activated the html5 mode true and unable to open the link in new tab.Do you have any solution.

Comment: I think that is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript, you can set global variable.

```
function globalSource() {
    jqueryUrl = "http://xxxxxxx",
    angularUrl = "http://xxxxxx"
}
```

when you want to use.

```
(function() {
  globalSource();
  //Get your dom and change attributes src link
  //ex: var xx = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].setAttribute("src", window.jqueryUrl );
})();
```

Comment: @ user3762171 : In this way i have to load all file dynamically.But i need to set only some common part of the path.

Comment: Ok,Can i call `globalSource` inside from script tag?

Comment: Yes, you can.
If you want to use it everywhere, you have to load this file when document readyState equal "complete".
Or your server can dynamically to set.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="Path" select="/crm/controller/"></xsl:variable> <!-- Global path variable. -->
<xsl:variable name="myScriptPath" select="concat($Path, 'productController.js')"></xsl:variable> <!-- Relative script path variable. -->
<script src="{$myScriptPath}"/> <!-- Attach script. -->
```

Comment: This will not work because HTML can not process your + (concat) operator.