# Javascript : How to get value of variable from specific file from 2 different file?

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic-data

I have 1 page that load Js file from another server. Its load file for each product in e-commerce store with its id in url see below structure.

Product 1: 
http://static.www.xxx.com/mydata/uXKojYEd9WXFpAasite/v4_3/1/d/itemjs

Product 2:

http://static.www.xxx.com/mydata/uXKojYEd9WXFpAasite/v4_3/2/d/itemjs

Product 3:

http://static.www.xxx.com/mydata/uXKojYEd9WXFpAasite/v4_3/3/d/itemjs

All Js files contain code like below

```
var MyItemData={"counts":{"q":1,"a":1,"r":2,"ar":4,"rr":0,"dq":1,"da":1,"c":0,"sdsd":0},"active":true};
```

Now I am reading this data in Html like below

```
var mycounta = MyItemData.counts.a;
    var mycountq = MyItemData.counts.q;
    var mycountr = MyItemData.counts.r;
```

The problem here is I can only get data for last product as variable `MyItemData` is the same for all files. I've to read each files by id but i don't know proper way to achieve it. does anyone tried something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop the answer below which loads external js file dynamically.

[How do I load a javascript file dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235321/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-dynamically)

On each iteration, read `MyItemData` and use it.

By using the function `loadJS` on above link;

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var listOfJSFiles=["http://static.www.xxx.com/mydata/uXKojYEd9WXFpAasite/v4_3/1/d/itemjs", "http://static.www.xxx.com/mydata/uXKojYEd9WXFpAasite/v4_3/2/d/itemjs", "http://static.www.xxx.com/mydata/uXKojYEd9WXFpAasite/v4_3/3/d/itemjs"];
var listOfMyItemData=[];

function loadJS(file) {
    // DOM: Create the script element
    var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
    // set the type attribute
    jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
    // make the script element load file
    jsElm.src = file;
    // finally insert the element to the body element in order to load the script
    document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
}

var arrayLength = listOfJSFiles.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    loadJS(listOfJSFiles[i]);
    listOfMyItemData.push(MyItemData);
    //removing listOfJSFiles[i] from html is recommended.
}

</script>
```

Comment: file is already loading on page. but `MyItemData` only takes data from last file. I've loop to load files per product.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you are loading those files using `script` tag. You could create an array to hold items and intermix script tags with inline scripts that save current value of `MyItemData` inside the array.

```
<script>
    var items = [],
        addItem = function() {
           items.push(MyItemData)
        };
</script>
```

Then call `addItem` after each script or play with `onload` event (not sure if the later would work).

```
<script 
src="http://static.www.xxx.com/mydata/uXKojYEd9WXFpAasite/v4_3/1/d/itemjs"
>
</script>

<script>addItem()</script>

<script 
src="http://static.www.xxx.com/mydata/uXKojYEd9WXFpAasite/v4_3/2/d/itemjs"
>
</script>

<script>addItem()</script>
```

etc.

Comment: No luck its give data of last files only

Comment: @Kul are you using `items` to access your data?