# Javascript src tag

Tags: javascript, src

Is it possible via javascript to change the SRC tag in `<script src="">` dynamically?

Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="change_me"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I'd rather remove the script tag and add another one with the new `src`. BTW an interesting question!

Comment: The real question is indeed: what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: #ehsan88 How would you go about remove and replace a script tag?

Comment: "Changing “src” attribute of <script>" Does not give an answer to this "simple" question... So the question stands unresolved.

Comment: You ask: _"Is it possible via javascript to change the SRC..."_, the answer in the linked question is _"It is not possible to change the src attribute..."_.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235321/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-dynamically.   And  http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml