# Load external JSON data with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying a JavaScript challenge but get stuck badly. The requirement is not to modify any other files except **`app.js`** and no library (i.e. no JQuery etc.)

Here is the **file system**:

```
css
  bootstrap.min.css
image
  1.gif
  2.gif
  3.gif
  4.gif
  5.gif
js
  app.js
json
  data.js
sample.html
```

---

Here is the **sample.html**:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Only Pure JavaScript</h2>
  <div class="contents">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="json/data.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is the **data.js**:

```
var sample_data = [
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "name #5",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/5.gif",
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name #1",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/1.gif",
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "name #2",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/2.gif",
    "price": 270
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "name #8",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/8.gif",
    "price": 70
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "name #10",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/10.gif",
    "price": 170
  },
]
```

---

And this is what I have in **app.js** currently:

```
var jsonFile = "json/data.js";
var len = sample_data.length;
// document.write('len: ' + len + "<br>");

var table = document.createElement('table');
var body = document.createElement('tbody');


for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var s = sample_data[i];

    document.write('id: ' + s.id + "<br>");

    td.innerHTML = s.id;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    document.write('name: ' + s.name + "<br>");
    td.innerHTML = s.name;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    document.write('thumbnailUrl: ' + s.thumbnailUrl + "<br>");
    td.innerHTML = s.thumbnailUrl;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    document.write('price: ' + s.price + "<br>");
    td.innerHTML = s.price;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    body.appendChild(tr);
}

table.appendChild(body);
```

I've spent so much time and tried 4 different ways and this one attached is the closest I can get (it shows correctly with `document.write`). Seriously, without any library or changes in the html page, it is hard for me. Any help or direction of where to look for information will be greatly appreciated. Remember, only **`app.js`** can be changed for this.

Comment: Look the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235321/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-dynamically?answertab=votes#tab-top) and then you'll be able to iterate the array.

Comment: `data.js` is not JSON, it's Javascript. You need to create a `<script>` element that loads it.

Comment: In `sample.html` there is already a script element pointing to `json/data.js`, which means that `sample_data` is already available as a global variable in `app.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need `document.write` ? Replace it with a simple `console.log` if you only need it for debugging purposes.

Moreover doesn't look like you are appending the `table` element anywhere.
Add `document.body.appendChild(table)` at the end of `app.js`.

However from your `sample.html` I can see you already have an existing TBODY element, thus you most likely want to add the values to that existing table.

Instead of doing

`var body = document.createElement('tbody');`

you can reference the existing element with

`var body = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]`

at that point you can remove the `table` variable completely.

```js
var jsonFile = "json/data.js";
var len = sample_data.length;
// document.write('len: ' + len + "<br>");

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];


for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var s = sample_data[i];

    //console.log('id: ' + s.id);

    td.innerHTML = s.id;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    //console.log('name: ' + s.name);
    td.innerHTML = s.name;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    //console.log('thumbnailUrl: ' + s.thumbnailUrl);
    td.innerHTML = s.thumbnailUrl;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement('td');
    //console.log('price: ' + s.price);
    td.innerHTML = s.price;
    tr.appendChild(td);

    body.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Only Pure JavaScript</h2>
  <div class="contents">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var sample_data = [
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "name #5",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/5.gif",
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name #1",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/1.gif",
    "price": 170
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "name #2",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/2.gif",
    "price": 270
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "name #8",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/8.gif",
    "price": 70
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "name #10",
    "thumbnailUrl": "image/10.gif",
    "price": 170
  },
]
</script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So just change `var body = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];` and it worked. I actually tried that many times but didn't include the `[0]` in the back. Why this is needed since there is only one `tbody` tag? Won't missing index imply the first tag found? Again, thank you so much.

Comment: @ian0411 `getElementsByTagName` always return a list, so you need [0] to access the first element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 1):

`data.js` is Javascript, not JSON. To load it, create a `<script>` element that points to it.

After the line:

```
var jsonFile = "json/data.js";
```

Put the line:

```
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + jsonFile + '"></script>');
```

Comment: I just noticed that you already have this `<script>` tag in `sample.html`. So you shouldn't need to do anything special in `app.js` to use the variable.

Comment: The problem is that you're never appending the new table to the body. I wonder why you're creating a new table, don't you just want to fill in the body of the table that's already in `sample.html`?

Comment: Give the tbody an ID, and use `getElementById`.

Comment: `document.querySelector()` is a good one which make it shorter. But is there a better way to replace my `for` loop to make it shorter?

Comment: Instead of using lots of `createElement` and `appendChild`, you could concatenate strings into HTML text, and then assign to `body.innerHTML`. But your method is much safer, as you don't have to worry about quoting issues.