# Calling Dynamically Loading JS method Using Callbacks is Not Working

Tags: javascript, callback

This code leads to :Uncaught error : check is not defined.Can some one help regarding this code snippet. Please find below code

The check() is define in external .js file

```
Method in script tag ...
    <script>

    loadScriptfinal("/js/VendorPaymentInfo/"+coreId+".js", function() {
                             check();
                            });


    function loadJS(file,callback) {
        var jsElm = document.createElement("script");
        jsElm.type = "application/javascript";
        jsElm.src = file;

        jsElm.onload = function() {
            callback(); 
        }

        // finally insert the element to the body element in order to load the script
        document.body.appendChild(jsElm);
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: `The check() is define in external .js file`

Comment: You're calling loadJS like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235321/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-dynamically right ?

Comment: My concern here is not about loading js, it's getting loaded, but this whole process happen in onload where check method executed before loading js. I wanted to restrict that using callback but seems callback not working

Answer (score 0):

You can watch till the external file is loaded and then call **loadScriptfinal** function.

```
var  timer = null;
var timer = setInterval(()=>{
if (window.check && window.check.constructor === Function) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    loadScriptfinal("/js/VendorPaymentInfo/"+coreId+".js", function() {
        check();
     });
     }
},100)
```

Comment: Why we need timer if we are using callback, is there other approach without using timer

Comment: timer is needed to check if the other file which has the check() function is loaded or not. Once its loaded it ll clear the timer and call your function.

Comment: Let me know if something else worked for you. My solution will work for sure.